# Nginx 1.9.10 & Laravel 8 gives response of text/html; charset=UTF-8 but expected application/json

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, http-headers, laravel-8

I have deployed Nginx 1.9.10 and Laravel 8 on Cloud server with conf file as below:

```
server {
# Set the port to listen on and the server name
listen 80 default_server;

# Set the document root of the project
root /var/www/html/public;

# Set the directory index files
index index.php index.htm index.html;

# Specify the default character set
charset utf-8;

# Setup the default location configuration
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Specify the details of favicon.ico
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

# Specify the details of robots.txt
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

# Specify the logging configuration
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

sendfile off;

client_max_body_size 100m;

# Specify what happens when PHP files are requested
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
}

# Specify what happens what .ht files are requested
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

But the api is returning Content-Type as html even though i am returning json from laravel.

Checked .htaccess file as well everything is in place.

Laravel: code

```
Response::json([
        "success" => true,
        "message" => "Success message here",
    ]);
```

Comment: Post the *code* of how you are returning json in Laravel.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin: I have updated the post with sample code

Answer (score 3):

I had also faced a similar issue, there was an extra empty line above <?php in one of my file due to which it returned text/html response.

Removing that line fixed the issue.

[Extra line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRmZJ.png)

Comment: Thanks @sagar It was really helpful. Problem is solved now.

Comment: Thank you. I spent hours on this 